# Is there a word or phrase for a choice that ultimately leads to tragedy?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Examples of decisions that ultimately lead to the downfall of the deciders:

- Troy accepted the gift of the Trojan horse
- Aladdin doesn't immediately free the Genie when he is told he will become Sultan
- Juliet's ingestion of Friar Laurence's drug

Is there a word or phrase that describes decision of this kind?

Comment: I'm going with  "bonehead maneuver" on this one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I propose **fateful**, as in *Aladdin's fateful decision* or *Juliet's act on that fateful night*.

Although it can mean simply "significant" or "determined by fate," *fateful* carries connotations of calamity or misfortune.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fateful

> **1:** having a quality of ominous prophecy [a *fateful* remark]
>   **2** 
>   **a :** involving momentous consequences : decisive [made his fateful decision to declare war — W. L. Shirer] **b :** deadly, catastrophic

More poetically, to express a stronger sense of menace or wickedness, one might use **baneful** or **baleful**.

Comment: Along the same lines is ill-fated. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ill-fated

Comment: @AndrewLewis "Ill-fated" (like "ill-starred," "doomed," "star-crossed") would describe the subject and not the decision, and would not work in all cases because it removes culpability from the subject, implying the disastrous outcome is a matter of destiny and not choice.

Answer (score 5):

I propose **fatal**. It was used in Max Payne 2 video game and just reading the question made me remember this quote:

> I had tried to run from it, edit it out. Winterson was dead, I was a murderer. A false start. The hospital bed wasn't the beginning. It was past the point of no return, the **fatal choice** already made, and it would get worse before the end.

Answer (score 4):

Tragedy has several characteristics, one of which (according to Aristotle) is that the protagonist must choose his fate. Although this is simply a choice, the wrong choice is made based on the character's *tragic flaw* (hamartia). You could say that the character faces a *dilemma*, i.e., a choice that yields pitfalls on both sides, but choosing wrong ultimately leads to catastrophe.

Comment: Neither of these suggestions work for these examples (or my intended purpose). _Dilemma_ only applies to Juliet. Had Aladdin freed the Genie all would have been well. A _tragic flaw_ is a  way to describe the decider, not the decision.

Comment: *Tragic decision* could fit this situation.

Answer (score 3):

I think *doomed* can also be used:

> **2a**: to fix the fate of : destine
>
> **b**: to make certain the failure or destruction of

From http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/doomed

Comment: How would you use _doomed_ to describe the examples in the question? Troy was _doomed_ when they decided to accept the Trojan Horse, but it seems odd to call the decision _doomed_.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the word *naivete* will do.

Comment: I think of _naivete_ as, the quality or state of being naive. However, Webster's does also list another definition, "a naive remark or action." However, I've searched for an example of a sentence with that alternative definition to no avail. For instance, all of the examples at this link (http://www.diclib.com/naivete/show/en/examples_en/N/756/0/0/1/25470), use my definition of naivete.

Comment: In keeping with the refinement you entertain, the phrase "one piece of naivete" stands in common use and perhaps in most cases is indeed referring to the actual remark _through_ which one's naivete becomes manifest.